How to add a progressbar shared with all content pages
I need to add a frame with a progressbar and a label to show in all content pages, unless I use "IsVisible = False" for it...
My idea was to add like 2 content page... One with all resources and etc and other with only the progressbar, which can be displayed or hidden... But I don't know how to achieve this
Something like this...


I changed the color only for display...
My AppShell:
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<Shell
    x:Class="Mobile.AppShell"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dotnet/2021/maui"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:Mobile"
    Shell.FlyoutBehavior="Flyout"
    Title="FactorPro"
    Shell.NavBarIsVisible="True"
    Shell.TabBarIsVisible="False"
    Shell.FlyoutItemIsVisible="False">

    
    <Shell.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <Grid Style="{StaticResource FloutItemStyle}">
                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="80" />
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="150" />
                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <Image Source="{Binding FlyoutIcon}"
                Margin="10"
                HeightRequest="50"
                HorizontalOptions="EndAndExpand" />
                <Label Grid.Column="1"
                Text="{Binding Title}"
                TextColor="{StaticResource LightTextColor}"
                FontSize="Body"
                VerticalTextAlignment="Center"
                HorizontalTextAlignment="Start"
                x:Name="_label">
                </Label>
            </Grid>
        </DataTemplate>
    </Shell.ItemTemplate>

    
    <FlyoutItem Title="Páginas" FlyoutDisplayOptions="AsMultipleItems" FlyoutIcon="factorpro.png">

        <ShellContent
        Title="Calcular Aditivo"
        ContentTemplate="{DataTemplate local:Page1}"
        Route="Page1"
        IsVisible="True"
        Icon="aditivo.png"/>

        <!-- ShellContent para "Gerar Contrato" -->
        <ShellContent
        Title="Gerar Contrato"
        ContentTemplate="{DataTemplate local:ContratoCarousel}"
        Route="ContratoCarousel" 
        Icon="contrato.png"/>

        <ShellContent
        Title="Clientes/Sacados"
        ContentTemplate="{DataTemplate local:MainPage}"
        Route="MainPage"
        IsEnabled="False"
        IsVisible="False"
        Icon="clientesacado.png"/>
    </FlyoutItem>

</Shell>


Why not have a progressbar on every page but a property bind to a property from a singleton. You can use dependency injection to make your singleton available to all pages that need to see it.
